# How to connect an external noise source file to openssl-fips-2.0.16

Tags: random-number-generator

[ECDSA][ECDH]
Due to Insufficient Entropy in Operating system of MCU

=> Could not generate random number by using BN_rand() function
(security strength fail, and RAND_bytes fail)

Below is my solution:

1. An external noise source file from TRNG

Eg: (80 bits), this data passed all tests

2. Connect (1) to OpenSSL by Engine
3. Invoke BN_rand() again
   (gather entropy -> seed -> PRNG)

Is this approach ok? if not, any other methods?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/jirka-h/haveged ?

Comment: Because we only trust the noise source from TRNG, so I am seeking a way to connect OpenSSL - FIPS to use this noise source